# Using a stateless class to change the state of an entity

Tags: c#, entity, separation-of-concerns, stateless

I'm developing an app that has to scan a Folder, its subfolders and its files, and I'm currently debating where to implement a Stateless programming paradigm to scan the Folder for its subfolders/files, or not. I'll share a quick example:

```
class UserFolder
{
    private int level;
    private String directoryPath;
    private List<UserFile> filesList;
    private List<UserFolder> subfolders;
}
```

This is how I've imagined the Folder class, I've omitted the public properties.

What I'm asking is if I'm violating SOC rules and the Stateless Programming Paradigm by putting methods like these:

```
public void ScanFolderForFiles()
    {
        ...
        filesList= new List<UserFile>();
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
        {
            filesList.Add(new UserFile(fileName)); 
        }
        ...
    }
```

inside a stateless class like this

```
class FolderScanner
{
    public void ScanFolderForFiles(UserFolder _userfolder)
    {
       //code, and save the data inside the _userfolder object
    }
}
```

or should I keep the methods inside the `UserFolder` class.

I know I'm maybe complicating things, so if you have a better suggestion feel free to write it out.

Comment: Stateless function is a function which operates only over passed input or static data. It means your 'ScanFolderForFiles' should accept 'directoryPath' as input, and return your file list. As long as you keep it in mind you are not violating anything.

Comment: @eocron would "not returning anything and just updating the filesList" using the Stateless function be a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, it means you modifying shared data (state, if you like). In fact, folders and files is shared data too, and you can't satisfy your condition as long as you do not lock this folder for this function only.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot.